# Rails Image Not Showing Up With Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am trying to get an avatar to show up on my main page.  I am using Paperclip to do this.  However, whenever I try to show the image I get this:

[image]

This is what my code looks like:

**View:**

```
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
      </tr>

      <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
      <%= debug @user.avatar.url %>

      <tr>
        <%= @user.username %>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

The @user.username does display correctly.  As does any other property I try to display.
The debug statement returns with:  "--- /images/original/missing.png?1400548644"

However, I can find the images here:

```
./public/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/myImage.png
```

It cannot be found here, though:

```
./app/assets/images
```

Is it getting saved in the wrong place perhaps?
Here is the rest of my code for reference:

**Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessor :avatar_file_name

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end

  def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
    if  EMAIL_REGEX.match(username_or_email)
      user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
    else
      user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
    end
    if user && user.match_password(login_password)
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def match_password(login_password="")
    encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
  end

end
```

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:new, :create]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :avatar)
  end

end
```

**Users Database:**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Avatar Attachment to users database:**

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while.  Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:
**Code to add avatar**

**views/user/new**

```
  <body>
    <% @page_title = "foos-tracker | Signup" %>
    <div class="Sign_Form">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
        <p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p>
        <p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email%> </p>
        <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>
        <p> Password Confirmation:</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%> </p>
        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
        <%= f.submit :Signup %>
      <% end %>

      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <ul class="Signup_Errors">
        <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**controllers/users_controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
```

Comment: The folder path for the image looks correct according to the Paperclip [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage). Are there also folders for the `medium` and `thumb` versions?

Comment: Yes.  And images for both as well.

Comment: What happens if you visit `http://<your-domain>/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/myImage.png`? do you get the image?

Comment: I get a Routing error if I try to navigate to that page.  No route matches [GET] "/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/myImage.png"

Comment: What is the response from `ls -la public/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/myImage.png` from the root of your app?

Comment: for that exact command I get:  -rw-r--r--  1 jonescam  staff  759 May 19 20:27 public/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/myImage.png

I also did an ls -la of the directory and only the Image File exists in it.

Comment: My only thought from that is that 759 bytes seems like a really tiny image file. Have you viewed the image to make sure there wasn't a problem in its creation by Paperclip?

Comment: Actually... no I have not done that.  And now that you say something it looks like there was an issue.  It is supposed to just be a DOWN ARROW (like a status).  And instead the image that is displayed when I open that file is a Blue Box.  Weird?  Is there something I am doing wrong when I try to create it?

Comment: Can you add the code from the form you're using to create the user with an avatar?

Comment: Sorry, asked the question before I edited the post.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: What do you get for `@user.avatar_file_name` and the other attributes [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage)?

Comment: Ok, so a little weird.  I get values back for everything except file_name.  File_size returns:  1121.  Content Type returns: image/png.  Updated at returns 2014-05-20 01:17:24 UTC.  But nothing for File Name.

Comment: That definitely makes me think something went wrong during Paperclip's portion of the process, though I don't know what that would have been.  Have you tried with other images since that one? I'd look for some sort of error output in your server logs.

Comment: Yeah I have tried multiple images.  Before your post I don't think I had tried anything that wasn't a .png.  However I tried a .gif / .jpg now and neither showed up either.

Same issue with both as well (where the filename doesn't show up)

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility it has to deal with my form_for arguments?  I am not quite sure what they all do and they don't exactly match up with paperclips example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be a conflict with your `attr_accessor :avatar_file_name` in the `User` model. You're creating your own `avatar_file_name` attribute and perhaps Paperclip is hitting a conflict when trying to use that itself.

I suggest removing the `attr_accessor :avatar_file_name` line.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for working through this with me. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

This is tagged as Rails 4, so I think the strong parameter whitelisting in your controller should do fine.  Take out the `attr_accessor :avatar_file_name`and it should work.

Comment: you should leave a comment on crsven answer because you stated the same answer as he stated.